# How do I install the manual pages on NetBSD?

Tags: software-installation, man, documentation, netbsd

I've done a "Minimal" installation of NetBSD 9.3 from the ISO image, just to examine the behavior of one particular command (`mktemp`) as it differs from Linux.

I'm not seeing man pages for… really anything; not even `man man` works. Cursory searches of the [Guide](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/), [r/NetBSD on Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/NetBSD/search?q=man+page&restrict_sr=on), and [the netbsd-users mailing list archives](https://marc.info/?l=netbsd-users&w=2&r=1&s=man+page&q=b) have not turned up anything helpful.

I also ran `pkgin search man` thinking there might be a `man-pages` or `manpages` binary package, but all I saw was a package for *Linux* man pages.

How do I get the man pages for the basic, built-in stuff *after* finishing a "Minimal" installation of NetBSD?

Answer (score 3):

Run `sysinst`, then:

- choose "Re-install sets or install additional sets" from the main menu
- choose "current system" from "Available disks" when prompted
- choose "Custom installation" at the next step
- choose the "Manual pages" distribution set at the next step, then "Install sets"
- if you have the original ISO lying around, you can choose "CD-ROM / DVD …"
- proceed through the rest of the process and quit `sysinst`

[image: Screenshot of the sysinst main menu, with "Reinstall sets or install additional sets" highlighted]

Run `man man` to test that it worked.

Be aware that this is overwriting *other* packages on your system with potentially older versions from the original install media. So it's advisable to do it early in the process, or just *don't* choose "Minimal" during initial installation.